# C++ でのバッファの扱い

Tags: c++

C++ 初心者です。
現在 SSL を利用したプロクラムを制作しています。
その中で、以下のようなコードを書くことになりました。

```
    int buf_size = 256;
    char buf[buf_size];
    int read_size;
    stringstream original_string;

    do {
        read_size = SSL_read(ssl, buf, buf_size);
        original_string << buf;
        memset(buf, 0, buf_size);
    } while(read_size > 0);
```

`memset(buf, 0, buf_size);` が無駄だと思っているのですが、`char[]` の指定した箇所のみ `stringstream` に追加することは可能でしょうか？ （せっかく `read_size` で取得できているので……）
また、このような場面で `stringstream` を利用するのは正しいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`stringstream::write()`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/write.html)を使えば範囲を指定して追加できます。

```
do {
    read_size = SSL_read(ssl, buf, buf_size);
    original_string.write(buf, buf_size);
} while(read_size > 0);
```

単純に結合するだけなら`std::string`でも十分に思います。この場合[`string::append()`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/basic_string/append.html)です。

```
std::string original_string;
do {
    read_size = SSL_read(ssl, buf, buf_size);
    original_string.append(buf, buf_size);
} while(read_size > 0);
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
`std::string` でも十分とのことですが、パフォーマンス的な差異があるかご存知でしょうか？

Comment: @AkiraKido 質問文の範囲では判断できません。`original_string`がこの後どのように使われるかに依存しますし、事前に長さが得られているのであればバッファサイズを指定することでパフォーマンスを向上させることができます。もっといえば一時的に`char buf[]`に書き込むのではなく直接`std::string`に書き込む等もできるはずです。ですので`std::stringstream`と`std::string`との差は些細な問題かと思われます。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

もしかしたらセキュリティ的意図があるのかもしれません。 `SSL_read` で読み込んだ値がセキュリティ的に重大な値（パスワードの類）であって、攻撃者が定期的にメモリダンプを取ることで当該データを読み取ることが（不可能には決してならないわけですが）困難になるようにメモリクリアを行っているのかもしれません。

`memset` の後で `buf` を使用していないので、コンパイラは `memset` の（インライン）呼出しを生成しなくてよいことになっているため、セキュリティ対策として役に立たないことがあるから要注意ってのは JPCERT でも指摘があります。
https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-msc06-c.html
`memset_s` なり `SecureZeroMemory` なり `explicit_bzero` なりはこの最適化を禁止し、セキュリティ的用途に使えることが保証されているようです。